# How to implement Workflow 4.0 Services ReceiveAndSendReply activity without the Designer

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflowservice

I want to write a code activity as a workflow service, using the Receive or ReceiveAndSendReply activities, but I do not want to use the Designer. What's the best way to define the WCF endpoint and service/data contracts (the Designer would normally determine them and build them into a xamlx file, but I want to do all this in code).

Answer (score 1):

The Receive and SendReply are just classes you can new. Take a look at [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/08/05/combining-wcf-and-wf4.aspx) blog post where I create WF4 service using just code.

BTW the ReceiveAndSendReplyis not an activity but a template that preconfigures a Receive and SendReply inside of a Sequence for you when you drag it onto the design surface.

Comment: Thanks Maurice. Your sample code looks to be based on WF4 Beta, which has different properties and names for classes. Any chance of the equivalent for the released WF 4.0?